# How can i make this python code quicklier?

Tags: python, arrays, list, performance, time

How can i make this code more quicklier?

```
def add_may_go(x,y):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(-2,3):
        cur_y = y + i 
        if cur_y < 0 or cur_y >= board_order:
            continue
        for j in range(-2,3):
            cur_x = x+j
            if (i == 0 and j == 0) or cur_x < 0 or cur_x >= board_order or [cur_y,cur_x] in huge_may_go:
                continue
            if not public_grid[cur_y][cur_x]:
                huge_may_go.append([cur_y,cur_x])
                counter += 1
    return counter
```

---

INPUT:

something like: add_may_go(8,8), add_may_go(8,9) ...

huge_may_go is a huge list like:

[[7,8],[7,9], [8,8],[8,9],[8,10]....]

public_grid is also a huge list, the size is same as board_order*board_order

every content it have has to possble from : 0 or 1

like:
[
[0,1,0,1,0,1,1,...(board_order times), 0, 1],
... board_order times
[1,0,1,1,0,0,1,...(board_order times), 0, 1],
]

### an board_order is a global variable which usually is 19 (sometimes it is 15 or 20)

It runs toooooooo slowy now. This function is gonna run for hundreds time. Any possible suggestions is ok!

I have tried numpy. But numpy make it more slowly! Please help

Comment: Please give us an explaination about how that code works.

Comment: How did you measure the performance?

Comment: This is a piece of quite bad looking code with no docstring and bad variables naming. I'd go with making it readable first and then optimize the performance to be honest.

Comment: post the shape of `public_grid` and `len(huge_may_go)`. Then , post the context where you call `add_may_go(x,y)`

Comment: seems like a perfect candidate for [pypy](https://www.pypy.org/) to speed it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to provide a definitive improvement without sample data and a bit more context. Using numpy would be beneficial if you can manage to perform all the calls (i.e. all (x,y) coordinate values) in a single operation.  There are also strategies based on sets that could work but you would need to maintain additional data structures in parallel with the public_grid.

Based only on that piece of code, and without changing the rest of the program, there are a couple of things you could do that will provide small performance improvements:

- loop only on eligible coordinates rather than skip invalid ones (outside of board)
- only compute the curr_x, curr_y values once (track them in a dictionary for each x,y pairs).  This is assuming that the same x,y coordinates are used in multiple calls to the function.
- use comprehensions when possible
- use set operations to avoid duplicate coordinates in huge_may_go

.

```
hugeCoord = dict() # keep track of the offset coordinates
def add_may_go(x,y):
    # compute coordinates only once (the first time)
    if (x,y) not in hugeCoord: 
        hugeCoord[x,y] = [(cx,cy) 
                          for cy in range(max(0,y-2),min(board_order,y+3))
                          for cx in range(max(0,x-2),min(board_order,x+3))
                          if cx != x or cy != y]

    # get the resulting list of coordinates using a comprehension
    fit = {(cy,cx) for cx,cy in hugeCoord[x,y] if not public_grid[cy][cx]}
    fit.difference_update(huge_may_go) # use set to avoid duplicates
    huge_may_go.extend(fit)
    return len(fit)
```

*Note that, if `huge_may_go` was a set instead of a list, adding to it without repetitions would be more efficient because you could update it directly (and return the difference in size)*

Comment: Sorry i didn't get the meaning of "compute coordinates only once (the first time)". If i input add_may_go(8,8) and add_may_go(8,9), why do the hugeCoord only  compute once? May you explain that?

Comment: The coordinates for (8,8) won't be computed again if you call add_may_go(8,8) a second time. If you don't go through the same coordinates multiple times, then there will be no benefits to this. Since you mentioned calling the functions hundreds of times, I assumed you would be calling the function with the same coordinates more than once.

Comment: Thanks! What you have said is right! I need to look at it for many times!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solve my problem! The program run much more faster! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I want to highlight 2 places which need special attention.

```
if (...) [cur_y,cur_x] in huge_may_go:
```

Unlike rest of conditions, this is not arithmetic condition, but contains check, if `huge_may_go` is `list` it does take O(n) time or speaking simply is proportional to number of elements in list.

```
huge_may_go.append([cur_y,cur_x])
```

[PythonWiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) described `.append` method of list as O(1) but with disclaimer that *Individual actions may take surprisingly long, depending on the history of the container.* You might use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects) as replacement for `list` which was designed with performance of insert (at either end) in mind.

If `huge_may_go` must not contain duplicates and you do not care about order, then you might use `set` rather than `list` and use it for keeping `tuple`s of y,x (`set` is unable to hold `list`s). When using `.add` method of `set` you might skip contains check, as adding existing element will have not any effect, consider that

```
s = set()
s.add((1,2))
s.add((3,4))
s.add((1,2))
print(s)
```

gives output

```
{(1, 2), (3, 4)}
```

If you would then need some contains check, `set` contains check is O(1).

Comment: Right! i don't need to care "insert" but append and pop only. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> if (i == 0 and j == 0)...: continue

Small improvement; reduce the number of iterations by not making those.

```
for i in (1,2):
    do stuff with i and -i
    for j in (1,2):
        do stuff with j and -j
```

Comment: I wanna ask if calculate ( i mean -) would made it slowlier?

Comment: Not in my first example, but the second one would be slower because still produce all the pairs regardless of `if cur_y < 0 or cur_y >= board_order`. I'll delete that.